# no TypoScript template found on subpages

Tags: templates, typo3

I´m trying to setup a new TYPO3 6.1.5. I have already created a root template and checked the necessary boxes. No use of `realurl` at the moment. I also included the `css styled content` template already. I have also created a subpage with an extension template with just a single line of code to use another html template file.

The homepage is rendered with template and everything, but when clicking on a button, there occurs the following error:

Service Unavailable (503)

```
No TypoScript template found!
```

Comment: maybe the "button" or better the link targets to an URL where typoscript is not included

Comment: Can you please add the typoscript you used and the HTML result or a link to the site (maybe a fiddle)?